# Substitute a sentence of a text, with the corresponding sentence of another text using Perl

Tags: regex, perl, hashtable, substitution

I've a text file like this

```
mc1s2  L#'|NA|det indice|indice|nc Sensex|NA|adj
progressait|progresser|v de|de|prep
```

and another file text like this

```
programmer:_[1]_:_P0_(P1)=1 progresser:_[1]_:_P0=1 
prohiber:_[1]_:_P0_P1=1
projeter:_[3]_:_P0_P1=1;_:_P0_P1_(PL)=1;_:_P0_P1_(PP<sur>)=1
```

I would like to have a replace in order to create a third file text like this

```
mc1s2  L#'|NA|det indice|indice|nc Sensex|NA|adj
progresser:_[1]_:_P0=1 de|de|prep As you can see I'd like to replace
progressait|progresser|v with progresser:_[1]_:_P0=1.
```

I would like to do this for all verbs.

This script answer to my exigence but I can't understand the last part of it

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $lookupfile = 'lookup.txt';
# Contains:
# programmer:_[1]_:_P0_(P1)=1
# progresser:_[1]_:_P0=1 
# prohiber:_[1]_:_P0_P1=1
# projeter:_[3]_:_P0_P1=1;_:_P0_P1_(PL)=1;_:_P0_P1_(PP<sur>)=1

my $datafile = 'data.txt';
# Contains:
# mc1s2  L#'|NA|det indice|indice|nc Sensex|NA|adj progressait|progresser|v de|de|prep 

my %lookup;
open my $fh, '<', $lookupfile;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my ($field) = split ':';
    $lookup{$field} = $_;
}

# use Data::Dump; # Used to debug the lookup table.
# dd \%lookup;

open $fh, '<', $datafile; while (<$fh>) {
    s{(?<=\s)(\S+)} {
        my $entry = $1;
        my @fields = split '\|', $entry;
        $lookup{$fields[1]} // $entry;
    }eg;

    print;
}
```

I can't understand this :

```
open $fh, '<', $datafile;
while (<$fh>) {
    s{(?<=\s)(\S+)}{
        my $entry = $1;
        my @fields = split '\|', $entry;
        $lookup{$fields[1]} // $entry;
    }eg;
```

Can you help me?

Comment: This is code that I provided to another question about a week ago.  I would've suggested that you simply reply in a comment to that answer, but for some reason the Question no longer exists on stackoverflow.  annoying :/

Comment: for this reason I wrote again the code! Thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This substitution

```
s{(?<=\s)(\S+)}{
    my $entry = $1;
    my @fields = split '\|', $entry;
    $lookup{$fields[1]} // $entry;
}eg;
```

uses the `/e` modifier, which indicates that the replacement string is not to be used directly, but *executed* as Perl code to generate the string to replace the match.

- The match finds the next sequence of non-space characters that follow a space character, so in this case `$1` is initially set to `L#'|NA|det`
- `$1` is copied to `$entry`, and `$entry` is split on the pipe characters `|` into `@fields`
- The `%lookup` hash is indexed with `$fields[1]` - the second entry in `@fields`. Here that is the string `NA`
- The code block returns the value of that hash element, or the whole of `$entry` if there was no hash element with that key. Note that, because `$entry` is the whole of the matched string, there is no change unless a corresponding element is found in `%lookup` because the string is replaced with itself

I hope this helps

Comment: @user3025314: Not really. What is your problem?

Comment: how can I print the result for all the text files in a final.txt ? Where the substitution is saved? If I write just "print OUT"; nothing is printed OUT;

Comment: @user3025314: I don't understand what you mean by *"all the text files"*. You mentioned only a lookup file and a data file in your question. I think you need to ask another question, showing as much real data as you can, and the output that you want.

Comment: @user3025314: Do you know Perl at all? `print OUT` will try to print the value of `$_` to the file handle `OUT`. It also suggest that you don't have `use strict` and `use warnings` in effect, as the latter would have warned you that the file handle was closed.

Comment: @user3025314 It should print all the lines to STDOUT as it is. So calling `perl script.pl > resultFile.txt` on your console should get you what you need. Also i wanted to mention: Great answer.

Comment: @DeVadder: Thanks for your encouragement. I was worried about the OP's use of *"the result for all the text files"*. But I believe he/she may be French and maybe I am not understanding too well. Perhaps `perl myprog.pl > final.txt` is all that's necessary.

Comment: Thank you for help ! I asked you for print because, I don't know why, the print Out was not going ! But now It's ok ! Thank you !